# Dependabot only looks at manifest files in default branch?

Tags: github, version-control, dependency-management, dependabot

I'm trying to set up dependabot (dependency version updates specifically) and want to test it in a side branch before merging it into the default branch, but I can't get it to "look at" the manifest files in the side branch.

I have specified the target branch as side branch, seen in my dependabot.yml file:

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "pip" # See documentation for possible values
    directory: "/" # Location of package manifests
    target-branch: "side-branch"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
      time: "13:00" # I changed this time manually to a few minutes after I pushed... idk if necessary
      timezone: "Europe/Berlin"
```

but when I give it an out of date Pipfile/Pipfile.lock in side-branch, e.g.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "~=2.2.20"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

it does nothing. When I put those manifest files in the default branch however, dependabot creates PRs in reaction to it. Is this the intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?